# Calculating the percent using a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble figuring out how to calculate the percent of certain letters within an input using a "for loop". I want to calculate the amount of X's and Y's a string has, and have the output come out as a percent but I want to use a "for loop" for it.

This is what I was able to do so far:

```
def percent(string):
    counter = 0
    for stuff in string:
        if "X" in string:
            counter = counter + 1
        if "Y" in string:
            counter = counter + 1
            XY_percent = (counter / len(string)) * 100
    return "{}%".format(int(XY_percent))
```

I only want to use "for loops" for this.

Comment: Looks like you're on the right track. The first for loop doesn't do anything in your case, as you have a return in the body of it (also you don't use the `stuff` variable anywhere). I would start with that.

Comment: I doubt the `return` is actually inside the `for` loop. That's just an indentation error. (OP didn't get the indentation right when copy/pasting, and an editor came by afterwards and moved it there erroneously.)

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but `str.format` supports percentages directly.  Using `'{:.0%}'.format(0.1)` will make the string `"10%"`, for example.  No need to multiply by 100 and convert to integer.

Comment: @Shadow, oh I didn't notice that!

Comment: @wim, I didn't know that, thank you for letting me know!!!!

Comment: @smarx, the return was supposed to be for the "for" loop, but I guess I made a mistake, it's fixed now though. Thank you for pointing that out!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if "X" in string` is the problem... this is always `True` as long as there's at least one `"X"` in the string.

Instead, test each letter individually. (I renamed `stuff` to `letter` for clarity.)

```
def percent(text):
    counter = 0
    for letter in text:
        if letter == "X" or letter == "Y":
            counter += 1
    return "{}%".format(int(counter / len(text) * 100))

print(percent("XYZZZ"))  # 40%
```

**EDIT**

Using list comprehension and @wim's tip about formatting percentages:

```
def percent(text):
    return "{:.0%}".format(sum(letter in "XY" for letter in text) / len(text))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need, note that indentation is important...

```
def percent(string):
    counter = 0
    for stuff in string:
        if stuff == "X" or stuff == "Y":
            counter += 1
    XY_percent = (counter / len(string)) * 100
    return "{}%".format(int(XY_percent))
```

You could also do it more concisely as

```
XY_percent = sum(c in 'XY' for c in string) / len(string)
```